# Which part of app.js file is my index.js file missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, middleware

This works
app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const session = require("express-session");
const passport = require("passport");
const crypto = require("crypto");
const routes = require("./routes");
const connection = require("./config/database");
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3001", credentials: true }));
const User = mongoose.models.User;

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);

require("dotenv").config();

app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const sessionStore = new MongoStore({
  mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
  collection: "sessions",
});

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "zdfbdaf",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: sessionStore,
    cookie: {
      cookie: { secure: false },
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    },
  })
);
function getUser(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ url: req.body.url })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("No user Found");
        res.send("No user found");
      } else {
        console.log("Sup");

        res.status(200).send(user);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      done(err);
    });
}

app.post("/visitor", getUser);

require("./config/passport");

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(routes);

app.listen(3000);
```

This does not

index.js

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const genPassword = require("../lib/passwordUtils").genPassword;
const connection = require("../config/database");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.models.User;
const isAuth = require("./authMiddleware").isAuth;

function getUser(req, res, next) {
  User.findOne({ url: req.body.url })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("No user Found");
        res.send("No user found");
      } else {
        console.log("Sup");

        res.status(200).send(user);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

router.post("/visitor", getUser);


module.exports = router;
```

The Error is "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" and I cant seem to find where I'm using "res" before or during getUser thats screwing it up. I'm p[retty sure my error is that app.js has something that my index.js doesnt, im just not sure what. I tried moving things around, like cors, but that didnt help.

(I comment out the app.visitor post route and getUser function when using the index page fo it, of course)

Comment: try to move ```router.post("/visitor", getUser);``` before the function or you can do this ```router.post("/visitor", (req, res, next) => {
  User.findOne({ url: req.body.url })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("No user Found");
        res.send("No user found");
      } else {
        console.log("Sup");

        res.status(200).send(user);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
});```

Comment: Neither of those worked. I had tried doing the 2nd option you gave already, but tried it again. No go.